# PHP undefined variable error, but it's defined

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to populate a `select` with elements of the database, but the select is always empty. I tried the PHP part independently and it works.

I get always the same error: `Undefined variable: countries` at the `<select>` line. However, it's defined, firstly because it's set to an empty string, and secondly, because as I said, the connection and retrieving of data is working.

So what may be the problem?

```
<?php
        #Connection with the database
        try{
            $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=php_test;host=localhost','root','mysql');
        }
        catch (PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit();
        }

        #Get the list of countries
        $query = "SELECT country FROM countries";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $countries = "";
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $countries .= '<option value= "'.$row['country'].'">'.$row['country'].'</option>';
        }
?>
```

Then inside a form:

```
    <label for="country">Country:</label>
    <select name="country"> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($countries); ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: This, `<select name="country"> <?php echo htmlspecialchars($countries); ?>`, is on the same page?

Comment: both pieces of code are from the same script right? Or are at least in the same scope if one file is included in another?

Comment: yes, they are in the same file

Comment: The script is procedural or is the `#Connection with the database` in a function?

Comment: Check here the full code. It's procedural. http://pastebin.com/GHCDGtfb

Comment: When form is not submitted it is undefined, `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {`...maybe you meant to close that conditional sooner?

Comment: true... didn't notice that was inside the if statement. Well, put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `$countries` defined but only when the form is submitted. This code closes the conditional that checks the `POST` values. This will allow `$countries` to be populated on every load.

```
<?php
    $name = $email = $password = $password2 = $address1 = $address2 = $address3 = $town = $county = "";
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $name = sanitize($_POST["name"]);
        if ((strlen($name) < 2) || (strlen($name) > 50)) {
            echo "<span style=\"color: #FF0000;\"> Name must have between 2 and 50 characters </span> <br>";
            $name = "";
        }

        $email = sanitize($_POST["email"]);
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            echo "<span style=\"color: #FF0000;\"> Check the format of the email </span> <br>";
            $email = "";
        }

        $password = sanitize($_POST["pass1"]);
        if ((strlen($password) < 6) || (strlen($password) > 20)) {
            echo "<span style=\"color: #FF0000;\"> Password must have between 6 and 20 characters </span> <br>";  
        }
        else {
            $password2 = sanitize($_POST["pass2"]);
            if ($password != $password2) {
                echo "<span style=\"color: #FF0000;\"> Passwords don't match </span> <br>";
            }
        }

        $address1 = sanitize($_POST["addr1"]);
        if ((strlen($address1) < 2) || (strlen($address1) > 80)) {
            echo "<span style=\"color: #FF0000;\"> The address must have between 2 and 80 characters </span> <br>";
            $address1 = "";
        }      

        if (isset($_POST["addr2"])) {
            $address2 = sanitize($_POST["addr2"]);
            if ((strlen($address2) < 2) || (strlen($address2) > 80)) {
                echo "<span style=\"color: #FF0000;\"> The address 2 must have between 2 and 80 characters </span> <br>";
                $address2 = "";
            }
        }  

        if (isset($_POST["addr3"])) {
            $address2 = sanitize($_POST["addr3"]);
            if ((strlen($address3) < 2) || (strlen($address3) > 80)) {
                echo "<span style=\"color: #FF0000;\"> The address 3 must have between 2 and 80 characters </span> <br>";
                $address3 = "";
            }
        }  

        $town = sanitize($_POST["town"]);
        if ((strlen($town) < 2) || (strlen($town) > 30)) {
            echo "<span style=\"color: #FF0000;\"> The town must have between 2 and 30 characters </span> <br>";
            $town = "";
        }

        $county = sanitize($_POST["county"]);
        if ((strlen($county) < 2) || (strlen($county) > 30)) {
            echo "<span style=\"color: #FF0000;\"> The county must have between 2 and 30 characters </span> <br>";
            $county = "";
        }

        #Connection with the database
       try{
            $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=php_test;host=localhost','root','mysql');
        }
        catch (PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit();
        }
       }
        #Get the list of countries
       $query = "SELECT country FROM countries";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $countries = "";
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            $countries .= '<option value= "'.$row['country'].'">'.$row['country'].'</option>';
        }
    function sanitize($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
?>
```